# Which font is used in this 'Google Fonts' image?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification, serif

The typeface is the following:
[image]

Which is being used in an image within an article in *Google Fonts:* **[Emotive considerations for choosing typefaces](https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/choosing_type/emotive_considerations_for_choosing_typefaces)**

It's from the first image that appears in the article:
[image]

Things I already tried:

1. Searching across Google Fonts, but I just can't find it.
2. Inspect the image (which is an SVG). But it has no fonts, only vectors.
3. Used font identifiers, but none of them has helped me. They only show similar fonts, but not the exact same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It probably looks like Newsreader https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Newsreader

[image]

Comment: It totally is, thanks a lot.. it was kinda difficult to find as I didn't thought this was an "extrabold" variation.